# Why won't IntelliJ use tabs?

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation

As per [How can I use tabs for indentation in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534819/how-can-i-use-tabs-for-indentation-in-intellij-idea), I have gone through and set each extension to "Use tab character" as seen below.

It doesn't work though - IntelliJ is still inserting spaces when I hit the tab button.  Did I miss something?  Where is intelliJ's `[Please use tabs like I ef'ing told you to do]` button?

(FYI, I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.2)

**This looks promising...**
[image]

**... but apparently it's all lies :(**

[image]

Comment: just out of interest: why do you want to use tabs instead of spaces? I actually hate when people use tabs in shared code as the formatting is most of the time messed up on at least one machine or source-viewer.

Comment: @MichaelRitter it doesn't matter *why* he wants to do it, or that you hate when it is done.

I hate spaced indentation. It is equally as messed up on at least one machine or source-viewer.

But our preferences don't help answer the question.

Comment: @MichaelRitter Indent with tabs, align with spaces. It's the purpose of smart tab option

Comment: I was having a similar issue and Smart Tabs were the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have the option Settings->Editor->General->"Allow placement of caret inside tabs" checked.

Deselect it and try again.

Comment: Good call, but I checked that.

Answer (score 10):

Go to **Settings** → **Editor** → **Code Style** and deselect ‘**Detect and use existing file indents for editing**’.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you open up the .editorconfig file, you will see something akin to the following

```
# editorconfig.org  
root = true  

[*]  
indent_style = spaces  
indent_size = 2  
end_of_line = lf  
charset = utf-8  
trim_trailing_whitespace = true  
insert_final_newline = true
```

I changed it to tab and 4, closed the project and reopened it.
I know this is an absurd step to have to take, and have an open bug report with them about it.

Comment: Wow. Reopening the project did a thing! Without the reopening, it was reporting absurd contradictory exceptions

Comment: i had several files with different settings for `indent_size` so i searched the project and changed it to the settings i wanted. now it works, no restart nor reopening was required.

Comment: FYI, https://editorconfig.org/ says you can define multiple file types like so `[*.{js,py}]` however, our project had `[*.{js}]` with `indent_style = tab` and spaces were still being inserted. It turns out that syntax does not work for one file extension. Changing it to `[*.js]` fixed things so that tabs are now used.